# Poincare Series and Hilbert Polynomial of graded $S$-modules

Tags: commutative-algebra

> I am trying to find the Poincare series and Hilbert polynomial for graded $S$-modules $I=S \cdot T^m$ and $M=S/I$ where $S=k[T]$ is the graded polynomial algebra and $m \geq 1$.

I am not particularly comfortable with this material, so I was hoping for some help. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $M$ is free of rank $m$ (an $S$-basis is $\{1,t,\dots,t^{m-1}\}$) you get the Hilbert series $1+X+\cdots+X^{m-1}$ and the the Hilbert polynomial is $0$.

Comment: Apologies, I just saw this, and it is indeed helpful.

Comment: What of $I=S \cdot T^{m}$? Your answer is helpful for me, but is quite succinct and may not be as helpful as possible to future readers. No need to worry :)

Comment: @user3462 My answer is succinct because there is not much to say. If you want to know $H_I$ just look at the exact sequence $0\to I\to S\to M=S/I\to 0$ and deduce that $H_I+H_M=H_S$, hence once you know $H_M$ you know $H_I$, too. (But I think all I said is something obvious, right?)

Comment: True enough. That doesn't require explanation.

Comment: It seems that there will be integers $n \geq 0$ such that $H_{M}(n) \neq \mathrm{dim}_{k}M_{n}$. When would this occur?